# How to add in response HTTP data in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Now that to get data I call method from controller, that returns data as JSON:

```
return response()->json([$data]);
```

Can I add to this response global data? And merge this `$data`?

For example I have global `$user` object that I want to give away in each HTTP response to avoid the following entry in each method:

```
return response()->json(["data" => $data, "user" => $user]);
```

Comment: could you explain well what you expect to have? an answer has already being given, does it already answer your question?

Comment: Does one of the given answers answer you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own PHP class or function to wrap Laravel's response with your own data. Eg:

```
function jsonResponse($data)
{
    return response()->json([
        'user' => $user, 
        'data' => $data,
    ]);
}
```

Then you can call:

```
return jsonResponse($data);
```

This is just a simple example of how to keep your program [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If you're creating an application you're expecting to grow and maintain, do something more like [this](https://jamesmcfadden.co.uk/customising-api-responses-in-laravel-5).

Comment: @mj could you check my edit. Not sure if it was okay or not because the questions seems a bit unclear.

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi Yeah, that edit works. It actually makes the encapsulation concept clearer based on the question.

Comment: only issue is that if the `$user` variable is actually as global as _being accessible_ in this function. I hope the Question owner sheds more light...

Answer (score 13):

An alternative to @rnj's answer would be to use middleware.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/middleware#global-middleware

This would allow you to instead hook in to the request rather than use a helper function that you may decide you don't want/need later.

The `handle` method for your middleware could look something like:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $content = json_decode($response->content(), true);

    //Check if the response is JSON
    if (json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE) {

        $response->setContent(array_merge(
            $content,
            [
                //extra data goes here
            ]
        ));

    }

    return $response;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: if you are using the json helper ($response->json()) then you need to :
setContent(json_encode(array_merge(...))
or else you will have a error referencing the lack of a _toString callable on an array